# Calling REST API with RestSharp and deserialize response

Tags: c#, json, serialization, restsharp

This code calls the REST API:

```
using RestSharp;
using System;

namespace NetWebclient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var point = new Point();
            point.x = 1;
            point.y = 2;

            var rec = new Rectangle();
            rec.point = point;
            rec.width = 100;
            rec.height = 100;

            var client = new RestClient("http://localhost.:3000");

            var request = new RestRequest("rectangle/move/100/100", Method.POST);
            request.AddJsonBody(rec);

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start the request:");
                Console.ReadKey();

                // async with deserialization
                var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<Rectangle>(request, response => {
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Data.point);
                });                

            } while (true);            
        }
    }
}
```

The rectangle object class is defined as followed:

```
namespace NetWebclient
{       
    public class Point 
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public Point() 
        {

        }       
    }

    public class Rectangle 
    {
        public int width;
        public int height;
        public Point point;

        public Rectangle() 
        {

        }       
    }
}
```

When i execute the request these are the headers recorded by Fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost.:3000/rectangle/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/105.2.3.0
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost.:3000
Content-Length: 48
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"width":100,"height":100,"point":{"x":1,"y":2}}
```

And this is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 15:40:33 GMT
Server: Warp/3.2.6
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 48

{"height":100,"width":100,"point":{"x":1,"y":2}}
```

The error happens when i want to deserialize the response back to type Rectangle. The response.Data is of type Rectangle but all of the properties like response.Data.width, response.Data.height, or response.Data.point are zero or null.
What am i missing?

Comment: In this example the response is virtually identical to the JSON in your original request - if that's going to be the case why bother?

Comment: I'm not sure if this'd make a difference, but try defining your class properties as actual properties, with a getter and setter, not fields. Like I said, not sure it'd make a difference, but I seem to recall that at one point this was a requirement.

Comment: Thats it, i have to use getter and setter instead of public properties, thank you